# A step value for jqueryUI Resizable?

Tags: jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

For other jquery interactions/widgets there are step values.

How might I go about forcing a resize to increase/decrease to certain values?

Must I do something like this?
(side issue, for a more effective hack, how can I know which compass point is being resized?)

```
var desiredStepPixels = 8;
var containmentLeftPos = 100;
var containmentTopPos = 250;

$("#resizeDivID").resizable({
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
       var newLeftPxValue = $("#resizeDivID").css("left");
       var leftPxModulus = (newLeftPxValue - containmentLeftPos ) % desiredStepPixels;
       if ( leftPxModulus != 0){
            if (leftPxModulus>(desiredStepPixels/2)){
                var forcedNewLeftPx = newLeftPxValue + (desiredStepPixels - leftPxModulus);
                $("#resizeDivID").css({"left":forcedNewLeftPx});    
            }else{
                //force a round down on the left side
            }
       }
       //and then etc etc for top, width and height!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, apologies. Of course Jquery have thought of this!

it's called GRID
http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-grid

I apologise, I had checked the documentation but just didn=t see what I was looking for!